# Template linking problem C++

Tags: c++

I have a template class definition that needs to be in the cpp file. Adopting from http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13, I did something like this:

```
 // File "foo.cpp"
 #include <iostream>
 #include "foo.h"

 template<typename T> void foo()
 {
  std::cout << "Here I am!\n";
 }

 template void foo<int>();
```

I instantiate the template from the .cpp file. However, I need different types like foo(string) etc and I realized that I could only instantiate it once. How could I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: what error message do you get if you just append the statement `template void foo<std::string>()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to instantiate `foo` for each type you need.

```
template void foo<int>();
template void foo<double>();
template void foo<std::string>();
```

This is somewhat onerous, which is the reason many libraries tend to provide template function implementations in header files, so that any instantiation can be available to any cpp file which includes the header.

Comment: I don't think that _is_ the reason why libraries include implementations in header files. If libraries _know_ what types you are going to instantiate their templates with, there is a good case for doing the instantiation separately. However, most template libraries don't know what types will be used to instantiate them, hence the need to provide implementation in the header files.

Comment: Absolutely. Even when the set of types is somewhat fixed, for every new type introduced, all the implementation files for template functions have to be edited; that certainly violates code locality.

Answer (score 0):

The template specialization should be in a separate translation unit (.cpp file) and the template (generic) definition in a header file.
In the foo.h
add the definition

```
template <typename T> void foo ()
{
    std::cout << "Here I am! << std::endl;
}
```

In the foo.cpp use it

```
foo <int> ()
foo <std::string> ();
```

Comment: Do you really mean specialization, not instantiation? If some code instantiates a template and cannot see that there is a corresponding specialization in some other translation unit, that would violate the ODR and probably lead to linker errors or quite interesting behavior, no?

Comment: Took me a sec (I would have said it the other way round) but Christopher Creutzig is suggesting you replace "specialization" with "instantiation", and he's right.  To specialise a template is to supply special behaviour for a particular combination of types (like for `vector<bool>` (unfortunately)).